# How can I read the file without empty line

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listbox

I have listBox and this text file:
    " 1
    2
    3
    4
    'blank line' "
I want to read this file without blank line. I try this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("MyMessages.chat"))
            {
                var line = reader.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');

                for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (line[i] != " ")
                    {
                        listBox.Items.Add(line[i]);
                        listBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                }
            }
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Blank line does not equals to a single space. Using String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) instead.

Comment: What error are you getting? Try !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line[i]).

Comment: Also use File.ReadAllLines which returns an array of lines, don’t need to split with \n. Because on different OS line break can be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use `File.ReadAllLines` with a `Where`

**Example**

```
var listOfLines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
                      .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));

// add items to list box here
```

---

[File.ReadAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array,
>   and then closes the file.

[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only
>   of white-space characters.

[Enumerable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.